# Binary Heap module in Typescript/Javascript supporting min-heap and max-heap

Tags: javascript, performance, complexity, typescript, heap

About binary heaps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

The purpose of this module is to allow quick and efficient priority queue management, compared to linked list.
Efficiency: insert: \$O(\log(n))\$, pop: \$O(\log(n))\$.

```
export enum BinaryHeapType {
    min = 1,
    max = 2,
}

export default class BinaryHeap {
    public heap: number[] = [];
    private check: (parent: number, current: number) => boolean;
    private type: BinaryHeapType;

    constructor(_heap: number[], _type?: BinaryHeapType) {
        this.heap = _heap;
        this.type = _type || BinaryHeapType.max;
        if (this.type == BinaryHeapType.max) {
            this.check = (parent, current) => parent >= current;
        } else if (this.type == BinaryHeapType.min) {
            this.check = (parent, current) => parent <= current;
        } else {
            throw "Unsupported heap type";
        }

        this.heap = this.heap.sort((a, b)=> {
            if (a > b) return this.type == BinaryHeapType.max ? -1 : 1;
            if (a < b) return this.type == BinaryHeapType.max ? 1 : -1;
            return 0;
        });
    }

    public insert(val: number) {
        if (this.type == BinaryHeapType.max) {
            this.heap.push(val);
            this.bubbleUp();
        } else if (this.type == BinaryHeapType.min) {
            this.heap.unshift(val);
            this.sinkDown(0)
        }
    }

    public extractTop() {
        const max = this.heap[0];
        this.heap[0]= this.heap.pop()
        this.sinkDown(0)
        return max
    }

    public peakTop() {
        return this.heap[0];
    }

    private bubbleUp() {
        let index = this.heap.length - 1;

        while (index > 0) {
            let element = this.heap[index];
            let parentIndex = Math.floor((index - 1) / 2);
            let parent = this.heap[parentIndex];

            if (this.check(parent, element)) break
            this.heap[index] = parent;
            this.heap[parentIndex] = element;
            index = parentIndex;
        }
    }

    private sinkDown(index) {
        let left = 2 * index + 1,
            right = 2 * index + 2,
            largest = index;
        const length = this.heap.length

        // if left child is greater than parent
        if (left <= length && this.check(this.heap[left], this.heap[largest])) {
            largest = left
        }
        // if right child is greater than parent
        if (right <= length && this.check(this.heap[right], this.heap[largest])) {
            largest = right
        }
        // swap
        if (largest !== index) {
            [this.heap[largest], this.heap[index]] =
                [this.heap[index], this.heap[largest]]
            this.sinkDown(largest)
        }
    }
}
```

Code: https://github.com/Livshitz/libx.js/blob/master/compiled/modules/BinaryHeap.ts

Unit tests:
https://github.com/Livshitz/libx.js/blob/master/tests/libx.binaryHeap.test.ts

Extra: How would you suggest implement a generic object support for this heap? So we could insert an object (that implements a interface, lets say `IPrioritized`, that has a numeric value which will determine its position)?

Comment: *implement a generic object support for this heap* - that sounds like you ask for some additional implementation or extension for your approach. That may be out of scope